# Did Morris.js Bar Chart change the bar width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

As Title.
I want to change the width of bar chart.
Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpRv2.jpg
Change to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ONTK.jpg

I search the document , but I cant Find the option to change it.

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: You have so many tags included.....Yet you need to post relevant code where you got the issues.

Comment: see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558766/how-to-increase-width-of-morris-js-bar-or-add-space-between-bars/23725027#23725027

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old bu this is what helped me in the same case as above:

```
barSizeRatio: 1
```