# How to increase width of morris.js bar or add space between bars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, morris.js

I have this morris.js bar with multiple bars, i want to change width of the bars or make space between durations. From the below image is there a way to provide either more space between `Feb` `March` and `April` or is there a way to adjust bar widths?

[image]

Here is my code

```
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'morris-chart-bar',
  data: [
    { y: 'Feb', a: 75, b: 60, c: 5, d: 50 },    
    { y: 'March', a: 180,  b: 220, c: 140, d: 160 },
    { y: 'April', a: 300,  b: 340, c: 350, d: 270 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  barColors: ['#0B62A4','#f75b68','#4DA74D','#646464'],
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

you can test it [here](http://jsbin.com/roburiya/1/edit)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The api doc pages seem to omit several properties. You can learn about more by looking at the source, where I found these 2 guys:

`barGap` and `barSizeRatio`

`barGap` is an integer that sets the space between bars in a single bar group. It defaults to 3. Increase it to space them further, decrease it to bring them closer together. `barSizeRatio` is the proportion of the width of the entire graph given to bars. It defaults to 0.75. Increase the number closer to 1 to make the bars wider, if its =1 the bars will take up the entire graph, if its > 1 bars will overlap.

```
Morris.Bar({
  barGap:4,
  barSizeRatio:0.55,
  element: 'morris-chart-bar',
  data: [
    { y: 'Feb', a: 75, b: 60, c: 5, d: 50 },    
    { y: 'March', a: 180,  b: 220, c: 140, d: 160 },
    { y: 'April', a: 300,  b: 340, c: 350, d: 270 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
  barColors: ['#0B62A4','#f75b68','#4DA74D','#646464'],
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
```