# Morris Bar Chart consistent bar width

Tags: charts, morris.js

I have a bar chart with 7 bars, and then another bar chart with 2 bars.  The chart fattens the bars on 2 bar chart graph which is not very pleasant.

Does anyone know how to keep every graph I create a consistent 7 bar graph length?

This means that there would be 2 bars to the left, and then empty space for the rest of the graph if there were less than 7 graphs.  I tried just filling out the graph with empty bars but it worked to no avail.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase width of morris.js bar or add space between bars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558766/how-to-increase-width-of-morris-js-bar-or-add-space-between-bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature I guess was added, but not documented on the main site.  The configuration is "barSize: 50".