# How to reduce the gap between the Morris Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, raphael, morris.js

Scripts

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
```

HTML and jQuery:

```
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
<Script>
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  barSize: 50
});
</Script>
```

The chart is rendering fine but there is a lot of space between the charts.

How to reduce the space between the bars?

Image:

[image]

Comment: Your question is similar to following link: [barGap and barSizeRatio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558766/how-to-increase-width-of-morris-js-bar-or-add-space-between-bars)

Comment: I have tried   barGap attribute, but still its not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify barSize for make a big bar.

Example:

```
barSize:120
```

or if you want reduce the space you can add more date with no value or define a width for your graph.

**Example with big bar**

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.

  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  barSize: 120
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

**Example with more date**

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.

  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 },
    { year: '2013', value: 0 },
    { year: '2014', value: 0 },
    { year: '2015', value: 0 },
    { year: '2016', value: 0 },
    { year: '2017', value: 0 },
    { year: '2018', value: 0 },
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  barSize: 120
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

**Example with width**

```js
new Morris.Bar({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.

  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [
    { year: '2008', value: 20 },
    { year: '2009', value: 10 },
    { year: '2010', value: 5 },
    { year: '2011', value: 5 },
    { year: '2012', value: 20 }
  ],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ['Value'],
  barSize: 120
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;width:50%"></div>
```

Comment: style="height: 250px;width:50%" worked out fine for me.